# Converting big-endian byte array BigInteger using .netstandard 2.0

Tags: c#, biginteger, .net-standard

I have a code that works with .netstandard2.1/netcore3.0 because of [this constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Numerics_BigInteger__ctor_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Byte__System_Boolean_System_Boolean_) of `BigInteger` class. This ctor is not available for netstandard2.0, and I'd like to be able to achieve the same functionality without forcing netstandard2.1.

Here's the problem:

- Convert a string to UTF8, and hash it using Sha256
- Convert the byte array in BigInteger using big endian byte order

Here's my solution that works with .netstandard2.1

```
    static SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create();
    internal static string GetEncoded(string value)
    {
        var data = sha256.ComputeHash(value.GetUTF8Bytes());

        return new BigInteger(
            value: data,
            isUnsigned: true,
            isBigEndian: true).ToString();
    }
```

This is what the solution can be in netstandard2.0, unfortunately it doesn't produce the same result.

```
    internal static string GetEncoded(string value)
    {
        var data = sha256.ComputeHash(value.GetUTF8Bytes());

        return new BigInteger(value: data).ToString();
    }
```

Here are some sample values and their expected encoded outputs.

```
"encoded": "68086943237164982734333428280784300550565381723532936263016368251445461241953",
"raw": "101 Wilson Lane"

"encoded": "101327353979588246869873249766058188995681113722618593621043638294296500696424",
"raw": "SLC"
```

From what I understand, the `BigInteger(byte[])` ctor expects a little endian byte array. The few solutions I tried didn't produce the expected results, so I'm turning to SO for answers.
Any help would be great appreciated.

[Related update issue to net core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24575)

Comment: Note that your current check and subsequent reversal does nothing -- you're reversing a temporary array created with `.ToArray()`. This makes it unclear what your actual goal is, but if you just want consistent results, simply invert the condition (`if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)`), reverse the array properly (`Array.Reverse(data)`) and use the constructor that doesn't take an `isBigEndian` parameter and always expects the input in little-endian.

Comment: Good catch, thank you. I updated the code. `new BigInteger(data)` still doesn't produce the same value as the other ctor.

Comment: Some limited testing suggests `if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) data = data.Reverse().Concat(new byte[] { 0 }).ToArray();` will transform the array in the desired way (i.e. what you had before, but not as a no-op). It wasn't clear to me that you wanted big-endian semantics unconditionally, as opposed to just something that works consistently. (Optimizing this for performance is another matter altogether, of course, this is none too efficient.)

Comment: After few headaches, it turns out that the python and Rust implementations that I was trying to align my code to, were incorrect. The code you linked above works, but it incorrectly turns little endian to bigendian and appending 0 to it, before feeding it to BigInteger ctor which expects little endian. Thanks for your time @JeroenMostert

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code of the constructor you used: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/191ad0b5d52172366436322bf9d553dc770d23b1/src/System.Runtime.Numerics/src/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs#L256

You could adapt it in order to replace ReadOnlySpan by byte[].